# Prevent Java Servlet from starting if configuration parameters are missing

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I have a number of `<context-param/>` and `<init-param/>` settings in my Java Servlet application that are crucial to its functionality.  I want to ensure that each of the settings exist and that they have a value.

Ideally I'd be able to assure their presence before the application starts.  If not, prevent the application from starting in Tomcat and list the values that are missing.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [init](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) method which is called when the servlet first created.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
  if(/* getServletConfig() is invalid */) { throw new RuntimeException(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This appears to help me with the `<init-param/>` values, but not the `<context-param/>`.  Did I miss something?